# Is it possible to match old and new rows inserted by INSERT ... SELECT query by primary key

Tags: mysql

Say I do the following query in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (someValue)
SELECT someValue from table2;
```

Also, both tables have primary keys.

Is there a way to find out a matrix consisting of source => destination row primary key IDs after the query is complete?

So the matrix would tell us which rows were inserted, and which were the source rows:

```
25 => 52 // 25 was the source PK ID, 52 is the inserted PK ID
```

What's the best way to solve this, and is it possible to do it?

Is the only way to do this having a special column in target insert table and populate the source ID's in it when doing the insert ... select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `someValue` is unique, you could join table1 and table2 on that column and match them up 1-to-1.

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (someValue);
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend to use a special column to record the original id in the new table.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (origin_id, someValue)
SELECT id, someValue from table2;
```

Comment: +10. exactly. store the id from the source table as a column in the target table.

Comment: Thanks, another column was not an option in my case, but I was able to pad one of the columns with the source IDs, then unpad them after I've gotten my mapping array.

Comment: That makes me cringe to overload a column by stuffing another value into it, but as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: @BillKarwin In theory I cringe as well, but in practice when you have a table with 100M rows, just adding a column is not so simple.

Comment: @Tool At my company we use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) for such tasks. There's also [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost) which we're evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding a new column to hold the source row ID was not possible.

My target table had a 'description' column into which I stored padded description - first 20 characters I reserved for source row ID.

Just wanted to mention this as another possibility for those who cannot add a column or need an alternate solution.

Comment: Tool need your help in symfony